# How to maintain a long-lived connection between chrome-extension and native app?

Tags: c#, multithreading, google-chrome-extension, console-application, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to make Chrome extension to keep long-lived connection with native app(C# console application). If click on "refresh" icon on my extension tab, the console application won't get activated, and port.onDisconnect.addListener() event got triggered. From inspecting views -> background page, I can see:

```
    message: "Native host has exited."
```

Chrome extension can get the message from C# console app, and C# console app can receive the message from chrome extension. There is a event in the console app, once event triggered, info will be sent to chrome extension by Write(). If I manually run the console app, I can see info in console app when event fired.

Console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string message = "test message from native application";
        Write(message);
        //Read();
        Thread thread = new Thread(Read);
        thread.Start();
        ScanInit();
    }


    public static void Write(string data)
    {
        var json = new JObject();
        json["data"] = data;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString(Formatting.None));
        int DataLength = bytes.Length;
        Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
        //Available total length : 4,294,967,295 (FF FF FF FF) 

        stdout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //stdout.Flush();
    }

    public static void Read()
    {
        //// We need to read first 4 bytes for length information 
        Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        int length = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
        length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

        string input = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
        }

        //Write(input);
        return input;
    }
```

background.js

```
    var host_name = "myhost"; 
    var port = null; 

    var newport = connectToNative(); 

    function connectToNative() { 
        console.log('Connecting to native host: ' + host_name); 
        port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(host_name); 

        port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage); 

        port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected); 
        sendNativeMessage("Message from chrome extension."); 

        return port;
    } 

    function sendNativeMessage(msg) { 
        var message = {data : msg}; 
        console.log('Sending message to native app: ' + JSON.stringify(message)); 
        port.postMessage(message); 
        console.log('Sent message to native app: ' + msg); 
    } 

    function onNativeMessage(msg) { 
        //alert('received messge from native app.');
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        console.log('recieved message from native app: ' + JSON.stringify(msg)); 

        return true;
    } 

    function onDisconnected() { 
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError); 
        console.log('disconnected from native app.'); 
        port = null; 
    }
```

I want to use chrome to activate the console app, maintaining the long-lived connection. Then use port.disconnect() when necessary. Following are from Inspect views background page:

```
    Connecting to native host: myhost
    Sending message to native app: {"data":"Message from chrome extension."}
    Sent message to native app: Message from chrome extension.

    undefined
    recieved message from native app: {"data":"test message from native application"}
    Objectmessage: "Native host has exited."
    get message: ƒ ()
    __proto__: Object
    disconnected from native app.
```

**Update 1st:**
After modifying the code, it seems the long-lived connection works. But it does not work with the eventhandler in the console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "test message from native application";
    Write(message);
    //Read();
    string data;
    while ((data = Read()) != null) // (Read() != null || Read() != "")
    {
         //Write("Received to Native App: " + Read());
         Write("Recieved: " + data);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know C# that much but maybe you can't read the stdin pipe in a thread. I suggest using an existing library, for example [this one](https://github.com/anewtonlevey/NativeMessaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the response! According to your suggestion, I think I get the long-lived connection work. But it still won't work if I have an eventhandler in the program, which will be triggered randomly. Originally, the idea is once the event triggered, the info will be sent to chrome extension by Write() method, but right now I wondering if it is going to work or not. I am afraid that the native messaging only works in the way like: chrome extension sending info to native app, then native app response.